# Why am I getting 403 Forbidden "User Rate Limit Exceeded" while using the Google Translate API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I just started using Google Translate API for the first time, yet my requests are denied due to 403 Forbidden "User Rate Limit Exceeded". How is this possible?? According to the cloud console, I have generated only a few requests, but they have all been errors. Here is a screenshot where I got that info:

[image]

Also, Google says that none of my quotas seem to be exceeded:

[image]

Seems impossible that I could be exceeding any quote from just 5 requests. How can I better understand why I'm getting "User Rate Limit Exceeded", and how to make it stop happening?

As far as I can tell, I was using the default quotas. I've never been able to successfully make a call (using the official Python library). I later slightly decreased the quota just for funzies (the default is the maximum allowed value), but that didn't help.

Here is the exact code that I used:

```
>>> import six
>>> from google.cloud import translate_v2 as T
>>> c = T.Client()
>>> t = "The rain in Spain."
>>> r = c.translate(t, target_language='es')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/allyourcode/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v2/client.py", line 268, in translate
    response = self._connection.api_request(method="POST", path="", data=data)
  File "/home/allyourcode/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 483, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?prettyPrint=false: User Rate Limit Exceeded
```

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out! The problem was that the project was assigned to a defunct billing account. Unsurprisingly, by changing the billing account of the project to a non-defunct billing account, I was able to get a successful response to my requests. The error reason is pretty unhelpful!

Comment: I had to send Google a nickel. They wouldn't use my credit card to autopay since it was less than $1. I switched it to PayPal and they accepted it.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of trouble!  We had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Translation API limits
The API limits in three ways: characters per day, characters per 100 seconds, and API requests per 100 seconds. All can be set in the API manager in Google Cloud console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/quotas

The library will limit the API calls for the characters and API requests per 100 seconds. The API will automatically retry if you are making requests too quickly, and also pause to make sure you only send 100000 characters per 100 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I saw that page (in fact, I posted a screen shot of it). Everything in there appears to be alright.

Comment: re n / second limits: Good to know, but AFAICT, there is no way I am hitting any limit, because I have only generated 5 requests manually from the interactive Python interpreter. The console seems to be confirming that those are the only requests that it has seen.

Comment: re retry and pause: Good to know, but if that's the case, then it should be making my requests less likely to fail (at the cost of slowing things down).